# Grouping Bar Graph Data in Groups i.e. by area in Spotfire

Tags: graph, grouping, spotfire

I have plotted x vs y and now i want to group the data presented by a certain area it is in, is this possible to do? I have put it in the plot and can't seem to separate them by the different categories.

Comment: please elaborate and include some code

Comment: actually there is no code involved, im just wondering if there is a built in function that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can often use the 'Color By' to select a column containing the 'certain area' you mentioned.

If you could give some more information, for example an example data set and screen of you current spotfire it would help alot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for the "trellis" feature, which produces a number of subgraphs, one for each value of a categorical variable.